# How can I populate by bar chart dynamically with data from an api call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following Bar Chart here

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { months } from "../../helpers/utils";
import Axios from "axios"; //axios library to make requests to api

// Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Roboto, sans-serif";
function BarChart() {
  //retrieving data from api
  const [intentsList, setintentsList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/countintents").then((response) => {
      setintentsList(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
  // BarChart
  //const labels = months({ count: 1 });
  const data = {
    labels: ["Industry_solutions"],
    datasets: [
      {
        axis: "y",
        label: "My First Dataset",
        data: intentsList.map((val, key) => [val.industry_solutions]),
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
          "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
          "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)",
          "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
          "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
          "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
          "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)",
        ],
        borderColor: [
          "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
          "rgb(255, 159, 64)",
          "rgb(255, 205, 86)",
          "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
          "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
          "rgb(153, 102, 255)",
          "rgb(201, 203, 207)",
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
    ],
  };
  const options = {
    indexAxis: "y",
    // Elements options apply to all of the options unless overridden in a dataset
    // In this case, we are setting the border of each horizontal bar to be 2px wide
    elements: {
      bar: {
        borderWidth: 2,
      },
    },
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: "right",
        display: false,
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Chart.js Horizontal Bar Chart",
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Bar data={data} options={options} /> {/* Props */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default BarChart;
```

Which I would like to populate with data which I have:
[{"products":2,"industry_solutions":3,"about_us":2}]

so the horizontal labels will be products, industry solutions and about_us with their respective counts. This data was obtained from a sql db query to an api endpoint and I merely obtained the data from there.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that the response of API is

```json
{"products":2,"industry_solutions":3,"about_us":2}
```

```js
const data = {
    labels: Object.keys(intentsList),
    datasets: [
      {
        axis: "y",
        label: "My First Dataset",
        data: Object.values(intentsList),
        fill: false
  }
}
```

Above code will render the bar graph you are expecting from the data

Comment: the response from api is: [{"products":2,"industry_solutions":3,"about_us":2}]

Comment: Will there be another object in the array with same keys ?

Comment: possibly not there won't

Comment: @Sathessh Valluru So I require the bar chart to show labels as Products, Industry_Solutions and About_Us, and the data will be populated with 2,3,2 respectively.

Comment: If there are no other objects, then extract first object with index and use the above object methods to get keys and values

Comment: intentsList.map((val, key)?

Comment: No extract the first object from intentsList like below 
const intent = intentsList[0]
And then use intent in the data like
const data = {
    labels: Object.keys(intent),
    datasets: [
      {
        axis: "y",
        label: "My First Dataset",
        data: Object.values(intent),
        fill: false
  }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233235/discussion-between-max-and-satheesh-valluru).